# Eigenvalue of Orthogonal Matrix and Transpose

Tags: orthogonal-matrices

Verify that if $P$ is an orthogonal matrix and $x = Py$ then $y^Ty = x^Tx$.
Let $A$ be a real symmetric $n × n$ matrix. Then we know that there exists a real orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^TAP$ is diagonal. By using the transformation $x = Py$, or otherwise, prove that for every $x\in {\mathbb R}^{n}$,

$$mx^Tx ≤ x^TAx ≤ Mx^Tx$$
where $m$ and $M$ are the smallest and greatest eigenvalues of $A$ respectively. For which $x$ is it true that $x^TAx = Mx^Tx$?

$\begin{bmatrix}5 & 1&\sqrt2\\1 & 5&\sqrt2\\ \sqrt2 &\sqrt2 &6\end{bmatrix}$

Find the maximum and minimum values of $x^Tx$ for those $x$ for which $x^TAx = 1$. Giving no heed to orientation, sketch the surface $S$ with equation $x^TAx = 1$, and indicate on it those vectors $x$ at which $x^Tx$ attains its
maximum and minimum values on $S$.

$x^TAx=y^TDy$ and   $\lambda_{min}y^Ty\leq y^TDy\leq \lambda_{max}y^Ty$
but how to link it to $1$ and the surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your eigenvalues are $(4,4,8)$

So you your biggest $x$ will be something that loads exculsively on 4 eigenvalues

and its magnitude will be $\frac 12$

$(\frac 1{2\sqrt 2}, -\frac 1{2\sqrt 2}, 0)$ will work.

So you your smallest $x$ will parallel to the eigenvector associated with the 8 eigenvalue.

and its magnitude will be $\frac {1}{2\sqrt 2}$

$(\frac {1}{4\sqrt 2},\frac {1}{4\sqrt 2}, \frac 14)$

As for the surface, it is an ellipsoid.  It has 2 equal axes and one short axis.  The big eigenvector is the minor axis.

Comment: Can you explain why the biggest s will load on 4 eigenvalues and the magnitude?

Comment: Consider from high school algebra $a x^2 + b y^2 = 1$ (with $a,b>0$) is an equation for an ellipse.  Put it in standard form.  $\frac {x^2}{\frac {1}{\sqrt a}} + \frac {y^2}{\frac {1}{\sqrt b}} = 1$  We can see how these coefficients affect then axes.

Comment: Thank you! And another question: for which x is it true that $x^TAx=Mx^Tx$? Should it be all the eigenvalues are the same?